# Select from union of same columns from three tables

Tags: sql, union, vectorwise

I have three tables, **A**, **B**, and **C**.  They all hold different data, but have some columns in common.

If **A**, **B**, and **C** all have columns **C1** and **C2** then how can I look up a specific **C2** value using a **C1** value that could be in any of the 3 tables?

Basically, I want to do a simple look-up but have it act on the union of the 3 tables - and I'd prefer to not use a view to achieve this.

Note that this is an **Ingres Vectorwise** database.

Comment: *Keep it to basic SQL?* Show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: @njk The only working solution I have uses a view that is the union of the three tables.  I'd like to avoid the need to create a view.  The basic SQL comment is to stop people from writing stored procedures or anything before noticing vectorwise doesn't support them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do this by doing a union of the tables in the `from` clause:

```
select c2
from ((select c1, c2 from a) union all
      (select c1, c2 from b) union all
      (select c1, c2 from c)
     ) t
where c1 = <your value>
```

I've used `union all` for performance reasons.  If you are concerned about duplicate values, either use `union` or add a `distinct` in the `select`.

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by " a specific C2 value using a C1 value ",
but, whatever your query would be for the view, repeat that query and union the results,

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE C2 = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM B
WHERE C2 = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM C
WHERE C2 = ?
```

(The view is a standard SQL feature, and will make any query you write easier.)